# Set aliases globally for all users

Tags: bash, unix

I have certain paths, which are too long to type, so I need to wrap all those in one script as alias and source that script to my existing package code.

These should set alias permanently over that server or over the package, so every user can use the alias instead typing the whole path.

```
alias bc='bc -l'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i' 
alias grep='grep --color'
alias update='yum update'
alias update='yum -y update'
```

I have tried this but it isn't working.

Comment: This is not perl syntax.  Are you looking for a shell script, bash,....?

Comment: Put it into a start-up file, for all users something like /etc/bash_profile.  However, it is usually a bad idea to use aliases in a script, it can be a support nightmare.  If you have paths that are too long to type, then put them into an exported  variable.  If you have complex program calls (your aliases are all external program calls) then use functions.

Answer (score 10):

Old thread, but I figured out what to do using the great post from Shivams.  The following is step by step of what I did on Raspberry Pi:

`sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc`

Add the aliases to the bottom, you can keep comments to be useful, such as:

```
alias ll="ls -al"    #Adds alias for ll to show all files and folders

alias lll="ls -alh"  #Adds alias for lll to show all files and folders with size in human readable format

alias cls="clear"    #Adds alias for cls to clear screen
```

#Specifically for Raspberry Pi, I also have:

```
alias temp="vcgencmd measure_temp"    #Get the system temperature

watch_temp() { tMax=0.1; tMin=999.1; while true; do t="$(vcgencmd measure_temp)"; t="${t:5: -2}"; if [[ $t  > $tMax ]]; then tMax=$t; fi; if [[ $tMin > $t ]]; then tMin=$t; fi; echo "$(hostname) - $(date +'%Y-%m-%d (%a) %T') - $t (Max $tMax Min $tMin)"; sleep 5; done; unset tMax; unset tMin; }

alias watchtemp="watch_temp"          #Get reading of temp every 5s with watch_temp function, includes max/min
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to save, then then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit

They won't work for your current session, so log off the terminal and back in.

Comment: If using a Raspberry Pi, you get `VCHI initialization failed`, try: 

`sudo usermod -aG video <username>` ... 

Then log off and back on 
(taken from https://chewett.co.uk/blog/258/vchi-initialization-failed-raspberry-pi-fixed/ )

Answer (score 6):

This is not the way to do this. Instead you need to set alias in your `.bashrc` file.

If you want these alias for one tty only then put them in a bash script and source that script on that tty. You only need to change shebang header in your script from

```
#!/usr/bin/perl to #!/usr/bin/bash
```

Instead if you want these changes in alias to be permanent then you need to put these entries in your .bashrc file and they will be permanent.

If you want to make those changes for all users you can put that in `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` whichever is present on your system and then make `/etc/profile` to source it.

For example my machine is running ubuntu and it's /etc/profile entry is this way

```
if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
fi
```

So if i put alias in /etc/bash.bashrc then they will be available to all users.

Comment: adding to .bashrc file , only i can use those alias right ?
my problem write a script for all alias , and source that file to main package profile file , when i activate the package , every user should be able use that alias.